# How Can I Make My KVM guest VM Accessible from the External Network?

Tags: linux, networking, kvm

I am creating a kvm setup for POC.

```
KVM Host IP range: 172.21.158.0/24
KVM GUEST VM Range: 172.21.183.0/24
default virtual network with NAT forwarding :192.168.100.0/24
```

below are the guest vm NIC settings:

[image]

Now, I want to access KVM guest from external network.

What changes need to done to make guest vm accessible ?

Comment: Hi and welcome to U&L! Can you add some additional detail of what you are trying to route? For example, "I'm trying to allow Host A @ 192.18.100.2 to reach the VM @ 172.21.183.2" or whatever your exact requirement is. If we understand what you are going for it will be easier to answer.

Comment: Hello, 
Thank you.
i just wanted to add that guest IP range(172.21.183.0/24) is already an external network, now, i wanted to access the GW 172.21.183.1/24 if my guest vm ip is 172.21.183.114/24.
If i need to add route/gw to reach orhave to do bridging for it ? please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You are showing two different networks in the first block: `172.21.158.0/24` and `172.21.183.0/24` so these won't be able to talk to each other without some iptables rules.

What you probably want to do is start the guest with "[user networking](https://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Networking#User_Networking)". You can do this by simply starting the guest with no networking options (user networking is the default):

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -hda /path/to/hda.img
```